# Select dropdown shows blank when NG model is null

Tags: html, angular, drop-down-menu, angular8

I am trying to change the second dropdown to default "Select ... " option when i change anything on first dropdown. But i keep showing me blank space, i think the NG is adding extra Option tag in the beginning and i dont know why.

Here is my HTML

```
 <div>
    <select (change)="onDropChange($event.target.value)" [(ngModel)]="person.name">
  <option value='default' > Select Name</option>
  <option *ngFor="let item of list"> {{item}} </option>
</select>
</div>

<select [(ngModel)]="person.options">
  <option value='default' [selected]="!person.options"> Select Option</option>
  <option *ngFor="let item of options" value="{{item}}"> {{item}} </option>
</select>
```

Here is my TS

```
  person= {
    person: "sam",
    options: 123
  }
  list = ["kenny", "sam", "stan"];
  options = [122,4324,234,123]

  onDropChange(value){
      this.purchaser.options = null
  }
```

code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3xo9sv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 2):

It's because you don't have any option with `value = null`, wich is the value you're assigning to `this.person.options`.

### Option 1

Make your default option to be equal to null:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="person.options">
  <option [value]="null" [selected]="!person.options"> Select Option</option>
  <option *ngFor="let item of options" value="{{item}}"> {{item}} </option>
</select>
```

note the `[value]="null"`. Now, there's actually an option that matches with the value you're assigning to it.

### Option 2

If you don't want your default option to be equal to null, just make sure that the value you're assigning to `this.person.options` matches with your default option. In the code you provided it's `value='default'`, so basically you just need to

```
onDropChange(value){
    this.person.options = 'default';
}
```

Make sure giving proper types to your object since right now it's declaring it as number so you may have a problem. You may create your type but an easy/quick fix to get rid of this problem is declaring it as `any`.
Again, I suggest to define this better.

```
export class AppComponent  {
    person:any = {
        name: "sam",
        options: 123
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: wow, thank you for the help. Also thanks for making your response comprehensive.